# JPA one to many bidirectional mapping of same items

Tags: java, jpa

I am trying to map the following in jpa. There is a class Item which has a parent "Item" as well as a list of child "Item"s. Following is the code.

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
Long id;
@ManyToOne
Item parent;
String type;
String name;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
List<Item> items;
```

But only one "item" table is getting created in the database. Also when I am trying to fetch an Item, the child item list is empty.

Is this way of coding correct ? If not, how to approach the same ?

[image: Image of database]

Comment: What does your SQL table look like and what do your classes ACTUALLY look like?

Comment: "_But only one "item" table is getting created in the database._" You are creating an entity with self-referencing relationships so only one "item" table is expected in the database. Yes, this is the correct way.

Comment: Just be aware that loading any node in the tree will load **every** node of the tree transitively, since you made both associations EAGER. If the list is empty, that means the item has no child. What do you have in your database, and what does your test code look like?

Comment: Sorry, there was a problem in my java code for saving the items. But thanks for the replies.

Comment: Sorry, there was a problem in my java code for saving the items. But I am unable to understand one thing. The above relationship creates a single item table. I have attached the image of database in the original question now. It says that an item Hub has a list of items of type Circle. Circle has Hub as its parent. From the table, the child to parent relationship is quite evident as the Circle item has a parent id of 1 which      is the id of item Hub. But what is not evident is the parent to child relation like Hub has a Circle as its child. But in java code I can retrieve all childs of Hub

Comment: That's the basic principle of a one-to-many association: to know all the children ot item 1, you select all the rows who have 1 as their `parent_id`.